# Ignore folders in .couchappignore

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

My CouchApp has the following folder structur, where files inside the app folder are compiled into the `_attachments` folder:

```
my_couchapp
├── _attachments/
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── app-tests.js
│   └── index.html
├── app/
│   └── app.js
├── Assetfile
└── views/
```

I want to exclude the file `Assetfile`, `_attachments/app-tests.js` and the folder `app`.

My current `.couchappignore` looks like this:

```
[
  "app",
  "Assetfile",
  "_attachments/app-tests.js"
]
```

But this doesn't seem to work. All files beginning with `app` inside the `_attachments` folder are not pushed.

How do I define folders and specific files to be excluded when the CouchApp is pushed via `couchapp push`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little more experimentation I found a way: the `app` folder can be excluded by specifying `app$`, so the final `.couchappignore` now looks like this:

```
[
  "app$",
  "Assetfile",
  "app-tests.js"
]
```

Comment: I was struggling with this as well. Thanks for you post it seems to be a major contribution to the documentation in the area. It seems that it is a regex (as stated in docs), of one part of the file name. That is a bit between the `/`s or at the end. It seem you can to say the directory called `abc` that is at the root of the directory or all files ending `def' in directory `ghi`. You can improve your answer by putting a `^` in front and a `$` at the end, this should be done if the regex does not start/end with `.*`

Answer (score 0):

In case you arrived here looking for a way to ignore subfolders, you are just like me. Here's my problem:

```
my-couchapp/
├── node_modules/
│   ├── react.js
│   ├── url/
│   ├── browserify/
│   └── coffee-script/
├── app/
│   └── app.js
└── views/
```

I wanted to include `node_modules/react.js` and `node_modules/url/` (and all subfolders), but didn't want to include `node_modules/browserify/` and `node_modules/coffeescript`.

I was trying

```
[
  "node_modules/browserify$",
  "node_modules/coffee-script$"
]
```

but it wasn't working.

```
[
  "node_modules\/browserify",
  "node_modules\/coffee-script"
]
```

also didn't work.

The only thing that worked was

```
[
  "browserify",
  "coffee-script"
]
```

I don't know why.

Comment: Currently, couchapp only matches each individual path component at a time. So your workaround (only specifying the folder names) is correct, even though (unfortunately) it could match other things too.